# Will EE 3.x work with PHP 5.6+

Tags: cartthrob, php, upgrade, php7

I am running a site on EE 3.5.17 and I am trying to determine which version of PHP I can use without causing issue or conflicts with existing plugins, which includes CartThrob 3.2. The EE documentation says the following is required for EE 3.x:

> PHP 5.3.10 can also be read as five-point-three-point-ten. That means
> 5.3.10 is greater than 5.3.1, 5.3.2, 5.3.3, and all the way up to 5.3.9.

I am currently running PHP 5.4 for the site but would like to move to 5.6.4 or greater given the EOL issues.

I would appreciate perspective from the community. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is yes.
The documentation indicates that the minimum version is 5.3.10 but EE3 will work with php versions up to 7.2 depending upon which EE3 you install: [php 7 compatability was included in EE3.1](https://docs.expressionengine.com/v3/about/changelog.html#id38)
HTH